# Swiper two way control with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swiper.js

Tried the example of two way control slider, but it doesn't work because of typescript errors.
Its example from Swiper documentation. is it possible to make it work with typescript?

TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Swiper | Swiper[] | undefined'.
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' is not assignable to type '(swiper: Swiper) => void'.

Have no idea how to fix em :(

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Controller} from "swiper";
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

const TestSlider: React.FC = () => {
  const [firstSwiper, setFirstSwiper] = useState(null);
  const [secondSwiper, setSecondSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <main>
      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        onSwiper={setFirstSwiper}
        // TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<null>>' is not assignable to type '(swiper: Swiper) => void'.
        controller={{ control: secondSwiper }} 
        // Error TS2322 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Swiper | Swiper[] | undefined'.
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        onSwiper={setSecondSwiper}
        controller={{ control: firstSwiper }}
        // Error TS2322 Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Swiper | Swiper[] | undefined'.
      >
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>Slide 6</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  );
}
export default TestSlider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise the state with the type you want it to have

You can import from Swiper but need to rename as it clashed with Swiper component

```
import { Controller, Swiper as SwiperType } from 'swiper';
```

Then when creating states should give a type

```
const [firstSwiper, setFirstSwiper] = useState<SwiperType>();
```

`undefined` is automatically added to type if you give give no initial value, if you want `null` need to use `SwiperType|null` as type.

Then for controller can check if defined yet

```
controller={firstSwiper ? { control: secondSwiper } : undefined}
```

And should work for types at least